# How to hide the default controls on jwysiwyg?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jwysiwyg

[jwysiwyg](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg) is a plugin that converts a textarea into a HTML [WYSIWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wysiwyg) editor.
I'm trying to hide the default controls it shows with their API's `ControlName:{visible:false}` option, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the code I'm using to hide the justify controls:

```
function make_wysiwyg(selector, content, settings) {
    //Create the wysiwyg thingy from a given textarea
    var default_settings = {
        autoGrow: true,
        justifyLeft:{visible:false},
        justifyRight:{visible:false},
        justifyCenter:{visible:false},
        justifyFull:{visible:false}
    };
    settings = settings || default_settings;
    $(function() {
        $(selector).wysiwyg(settings).wysiwyg("setContent", content||"");
    });
}
```

Any ideas on why it isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place the controls inside the `controls` property.

```
    $("textarea").wysiwyg({
        rmUnusedControls: true,
        controls: {
            bold: { visible : true },
            html: { visible : true }
        }
    });
```

Try to rewrite all the controls with `rmUnusedControls` from the [Examples](http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/help/examples/).

Comment: Thanks, I missed out the fact that they need to be inside the controls option. Also thank you for pointing out the `rmUnusedControls` option as well =), I didn't have much time to go through all the documentation (tl;dr) ...